# Update content depending on string in view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am running an MVC application, which have a view model like this:

```
public class UserListViewModel
{
    public UserListViewModel()
    {
        Users = new List<UserViewModel>();
        QueriedUsers = new List<UserViewModel>();
    }

    public List<UserViewModel> Users { get; private set; }
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }
    public List<UserViewModel> QueriedUsers { get; private set; }
}
```

- **Users**: The original users
- **SearchQuery**: a query which is returned by the view
- **QueriedUsers** :Users after Users are sorted

In my view, I have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "EditUser"))
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.SearchQuery);
}



@if (Model.QueriedUsers != null && Model.QueriedUsers.Any())
{
    foreach (var u in Model.QueriedUsers)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
else
{ 
    foreach (var u in Model.Users)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And this is the HttpPost code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(UserListViewModel input)
{
    return View("EditUser",NewUserListModel(input));
}
```

Before I click enter in my search field, I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:61162/Admin/Users
```

After clicking enter, I get:

```
http://localhost:61162/Admin/Users/Search
```

From my breakpoint I can tell the controller code is run.

The error I get in my new URL is:

> The resource cannot be found.
>        Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or
>   is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
Requested URL: /Admin/EditUser/Search
```

Which of course is caused by the url has changed.

Any hints how to solve my issue ? :-) I simply want to have a where clause on my Users, so I can show the relevant data depending on the search input.

Comment: The error message is pretty obvious, you don't have a view named Users.

Comment: Yes sorry, wrong error message. Updated post :) Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an `EdirUser` method?

Comment: von v: EditUser is my view :-)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard then that's your problem, your trying to re-direct the user to a URL `/Admin/EditUser/Search` but it doesn't exist. I assume you want `/Admin/Search/` but with the `EditUser` view instead of the default `Search` view?

Comment: This probably shows my lack of knowledge in MVC: I want to load the EditUser view, but with my edited viewmodel, so Model.QueriedUsers isn't null.

Comment: You pass `EditUser` as the controller name to `BeginForm` but the original URL (when GETting the page) contains `Users` as a controller name. Can this be an issue? Do you have an `EditUser` controller or where does the `Search` action belong to?

Comment: @volpav you mean an `EditUser` method in `Admin` controller. So, with all the comments you've seen here Lars, what you need is either: (1) create an `EditUsers` method that will return your `EditUsers` view; (2) or have a logic inside your `Search` method to know if you will return the `Search` view or the `EditUsers` view. I hope that make sense.

Comment: @vonv. I thought `Admin` is an area.

Comment: Ah never mind my last comment, I did not notice you updated your question and posted your `Search` method.

Comment: Did not mention it @volpav but looking at this url `http://localhost:61162/Admin/Users/Search` it may very well be. I need to step away from this question and come back again later, and read it again entirely :)

Comment: Gentlemen, I think we can compose an answer now :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I got really confused with the project. However, the solution was changing the Search HttpPost to:

            return View("Index",NewUserListModel(input));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @LarsHoldgaard's last comment:

> Thanks a lot for your help, I got really confused with the project.
>   However, the solution was changing the Search HttpPost to:
>
> ```
>     return View("Index", NewUserListModel(input));
> ```